# Are there any Apiary.io documentation sources available

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I use Apiary.io Blueprint Editor to create awesome documentation for server API. Now, I am still new at this, and I am trying to find out what are the capabilities of this tool.

I have seen examples like:
http://docs.gooddata.apiary.io/

And I see some things on this link that I cannot reproduce when creating my own documentation.
I really wish that I could download the "source" (raw Apiary markdown) of a documentation like the one presented in the link.

Does anyone know if that is possible? Provide a link, please.

Answer (score 1):

For that particular example, check out the "Fork me on GitHub" tag on the top right corner of the page. You can get to the source API Blueprint for the GoodData documentation.

https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-api-docs

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation and look at the top menu, there is `API Blueprint` tab that shows you the raw API blueprint.

However, the owner of the said API had to allow this option. If it's not present, you unfortunately can't see the raw file.